# SQL Query result have repeated values

Tags: mysql, sql

i Have three tables, 
1. ct_product
2. stock_in
3. stock_out

table structure and data is available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61d62e/1)

my desired output is

[image]

but my query output is

[image]

please how can i get my desired output?

SQL query is below

```
SELECT 
 (select product_name from ct_product where id=stock_in.ct_prod_id) as name,
 stockin.ct_prod_status,
 stockin.ct_prod_catgry,
 IFNull(stockin.stock_in, 0) stock_in,
 IFNull(stockout.stock_out, 0) stock_out,
 IFNull(stockin.stock_in, 0)-IFNull(stockout.stock_out, 0) stockinhand
FROM stock_in
LEFT JOIN
(
 SELECT 
   SUM(quantity) stock_in,
  ct_prod_id,
   ct_prod_catgry,
   ct_prod_status
  FROM stock_in
  group by ct_prod_catgry, ct_prod_id, ct_prod_status
  ) stockin ON stockin.ct_prod_id = stock_in.ct_prod_id 
  LEFT JOIN 
 (
  SELECT 
  SUM(quantity) stock_out,
   ct_prod_id,
    ct_prod_catgry,
    ct_prod_status
     FROM stock_out
     group by ct_prod_catgry, ct_prod_id, ct_prod_status 
   ) stockout ON stockout.ct_prod_id = stock_in.ct_prod_id 
  where stockout.ct_prod_catgry=stock_in.ct_prod_catgry and 
   stockout.ct_prod_status=stock_in.ct_prod_status
```

Comment: table structure and data is available on this link  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61d62e/1

Comment: Just looking at the results, you're missing a join critiera.

Comment: can you help me out xQbert plz

Comment: ok it was two fold 1 you needed to distnct from stock_in for the ct_Prod columns otherwise you were joining more than 1 row causing record duplication.  In addition the join criteria on the 1st left join is missing 2 ct_prod considerations.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a group by on the overall query, and add SUM around to items to total:

```
SELECT 
 (select product_name from ct_product where id=stock_in.ct_prod_id) as name,
 stockin.ct_prod_status,
 stockin.ct_prod_catgry,
 SUM(IFNull(stockin.stock_in, 0)) stock_in,
 SUM(IFNull(stockout.stock_out, 0)) stock_out,
 SUM(IFNull(stockin.stock_in, 0)-IFNull(stockout.stock_out, 0)) stockinhand
FROM stock_in
LEFT JOIN
(
 SELECT 
   SUM(quantity) stock_in,
  ct_prod_id,
   ct_prod_catgry,
   ct_prod_status
  FROM stock_in
  group by ct_prod_catgry, ct_prod_id, ct_prod_status
  ) stockin ON stockin.ct_prod_id = stock_in.ct_prod_id 
  LEFT JOIN 
 (
  SELECT 
  SUM(quantity) stock_out,
   ct_prod_id,
    ct_prod_catgry,
    ct_prod_status
     FROM stock_out
     group by ct_prod_catgry, ct_prod_id, ct_prod_status 
   ) stockout ON stockout.ct_prod_id = stock_in.ct_prod_id 
  where stockout.ct_prod_catgry=stock_in.ct_prod_catgry and 
   stockout.ct_prod_status=stock_in.ct_prod_status
group by name, stockin.ct_prod_status, stockin.ct_prod_catgry
```

Comment: are you sure the totals are right?  they vary from your expected results.

Comment: @xQbert may be correct. If the totals are too high, remove the SUM() function in the main column list.

Comment: While this generates results, they are doubled (and even more than that in some cases).  Thus I believe incorrect. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61d62e/52/0

Answer (score 0):

Two Problems two points of consideration (POC)

1. Missing join criteria on 1st left join
2. you need to distinct list of Ct_Prod values from stock_in not all of them.
3. POC ! Might as well join to product instead of running a select for each record.
4. POC!You can use compound criteria on joins and avoid the where clause which makes more sense imo.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61d62e/47/0 using in select query to get name
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61d62e/49/0 using join to get name [I'm a bigger fan of this approach]

```
SELECT 
 CP.Product_Name as name,  #I like joins instead of selects at this level
 stockin.ct_prod_status,
 stockin.ct_prod_catgry,
 IFNull(stockin.stock_in, 0) stock_in,
 IFNull(stockout.stock_out, 0) stock_out,
 IFNull(stockin.stock_in, 0)-IFNull(stockout.stock_out, 0) stockinhand
FROM (select distinct ct_prod_ID, ct_prod_status, ct_prod_Catgry from stock_in) stock_in  #needed to get a distinct list of ct_** to join
INNER JOIN ct_product cp
  on stock_in.ct_prod_ID = cp.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(quantity) stock_in
                , ct_prod_id
                , ct_prod_catgry
                , ct_prod_status
            FROM stock_in
            GROUP BY ct_prod_catgry, ct_prod_id, ct_prod_status
           ) stockin 
   ON stockin.ct_prod_id = stock_in.ct_prod_id 
  and stockin.ct_prod_status = stock_in.ct_prod_status #Missing
  and stockin.ct_prod_catgry = stock_in.ct_prod_catgry #Missing

LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(quantity) stock_out
                , ct_prod_id
                , ct_prod_catgry
                , ct_prod_status
            FROM stock_out
            GROUP BY ct_prod_catgry, ct_prod_id, ct_prod_status 
           ) stockout 
   ON stockout.ct_prod_id = stock_in.ct_prod_id 
  and stockout.ct_prod_catgry=stock_in.ct_prod_catgry #no where just and
  and stockout.ct_prod_status=stock_in.ct_prod_status #no where just and
```